# ¿Cómo eliminar un registro cuya id es usada como clave foránea y así sucesivamente en Laravel 5.5?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, php7

Estoy utilizando Laravel 5.5 y PHP 7.0.33.

Mi sistema tiene "Plantas", cada planta puede tener muchas "Áreas" y cada área puede tener muchos "Equipos". Considero que está todo correctamente relacionado, no obstante,

> ¿cómo es la forma correcta de eliminar una Planta?

Forma 1:

Dentro de `app/Plant.php` va lo siguiente y luego dentro de `app/Area.php` la misma función "boot" pero para que borre los equipos.

```
public function areas()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Area::class);
    }
    public static function boot() 
    {
            parent::boot();
            static::deleting(function($plant){ 
               $plant->areas()->delete();
            });
    }
```

Forma 2:
Dentro de `app/Plant.php` poner todo.

```
public function areas()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Area::class);
    }
    public static function boot() {
            parent::boot();
            static::deleting(function($plant){ 
                $plant->areas()->equipos()->delete();
                $plant->areas()->delete();
            });
        }
```

Probablemente no sea ninguna de esas porque no me funcionan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que Laravel no construye los modelos que elimina.

Entonces cuando haces `$plant->areas()->delete();` en realidad llama al método `delete()` en un objeto 'query builder', y no a una instancia de los modelos de areas.

Para hacerlo en la función boot del modelo, puedes obtener las areas y luego hacer un bucle y eliminarlas.:

```
public static function boot() {
    parent::boot();
    static::deleting(function($plant){ 
        $plant->areas()->get()
            ->each(function($area) {
                $area->delete();
            });
    });
}
```

Para lo de equipos no lo he probado pero creo que podrías ponerlo en el modelo Area y debería funcionar

```
static::deleting(function($area){ 
    $area->equipos()->get()
        ->each(function($equipo) {
            $equipo->delete();
        });
});
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Te doy un resumen rápido, me parece ya creaste tu modelo y migración (php artisan make:model -m "Planta") lo anterior crea tu modelo y migración, posterior a esto tienes que crear el controlador (php artisan make:controller "PlantasController"), es donde vas a agregar, actualizar y eliminar, ahora que va en cada archivo:

- `app/Planta.php` este es tu modelo, en el cual solo agregarás el nombre de la tabla de la siguiente forma, para referenciar a Eloquent tu tabla:

  ```
   protected $table = 'plantas';
  ```
- `database/migrations/fecha_create_plantas_table.php` es tu migración, en la cual agregarás las columnas de tu tabla, aquí es donde está la magia, ya que cuando agregas la llave foránea tienes que agregar ->onDelete('cascade'), por ejemplo:

  ```
   $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
  ```
- Ahora en `app/Http/Controllers/PlantasController.php`, es donde crearás tu función para eliminar las Plantas, podrás llamar este método desde el sistema de rutas de Laravel editable desde routes/web.php
- Punto extendido: Te dejo un ejemplo del código del controlador, primero agrega use App\Planta; justo arriba de donde se crea la clase y crea tu método:

  ```
  public function eliminar(){
     $planta = Planta::where('id',$id)->first();
     $planta->delete();
  }
  ```
- Ahora solo queda correr el método, ve a routes/web.php y agrega la ruta, con la cual podrás acceder desde el navegador, etc...

  ```
  Route::get('/plantas/{id}','PlantasController@eliminar');
  ```

La forma correcta de hacerlo es creando `Route::delete`..., siguiendo las buenas practicas http, pero para efectos prácticos con get te va a funcionar bien.

> Como nota, puede ser que no haya entendido la función que le estas
>   dando a ese archivo, por lo cual el punto en el que te debes centrar
>   es el número 2 ( `->onDelete('cascade')` en tu archivo de migración )

Comment: Hola, todo lo que explicaste lo tengo hecho. Puede que haya cierta posibilidad de que no hayas entendido mi pregunta o que yo me haya expresado mal. Yo me refería que al eliminar una planta quiero que se eliminen todas las áreas de esa planta y, a su vez, todos los equipos de todas las áreas.

Comment: Hola, a fin de cuentas revisa: ->onDelete('cascade') en tu migración. Esto resuelve el problema, al eliminar una planta se eliminarán posteriormente los registros foráneos en cadena.

Comment: Okey, lo miraré. Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Una forma de hacerlo es eliminar desde lo mas bajo, hasta la planta.

```
public function destroy($plantaId) {
    $planta = Plantas::find($plantaId);

    //Eliminar las Áreas y los Equipos de cada Área
    $areas = $planta->areas()->get();
    foreach ($areas as $area) {
        $equipos = $area->equipos()->get();
        foreach ($equipos as $equipo) {
            Equipo::destroy($equipo->id);
        }
        Area::destroy($area->id);
    }

    //Finalmente se elimina la Planta
    Planta::destroy($planta->id);
    return redirect('/home');
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!